# Amazed by a calculation of $x$, such as $P(X < x) = 3.60\%$ when $X \sim N(µ=1, σ=1.5)$

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function

My book has an exercise that asks me two questions:

Be $X$ a variable following a normal distribution,
find $\mathbf{m_{x}}$ and $\mathbf{σ_{x}^2}$ knowing that $P(X \leq -1) = P(X > 3) = 9.12\%$
(the expected result is that $X \sim N(µ=1, σ²=1.5²)$)

then, calculate $\mathbf{P(X > 0)}$,
and $\mathbf{x}$ such as $P(X \leq x) = 3.60\%$
(the expected results are $P(X > 0) = 74.75\%$ and $x = -2$)

I attempted to solve that exercise with a *Java* program, using the `NormalDistribution` class from *Apache Commons Maths* which is convenient for that case, and only differs from the exercise by the fact that it takes for second parameter a standard deviation and not a variance.

```java
package test.fr.ecoemploi.spark.inferentielle;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.slf4j.*;

/**
 * Estimation de paramètres
 */
public class EstimationParametresIT {
   /** Logger. */
   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EstimationParametresIT.class);

   /**
    * Estimation de Espérance mathématique m et de variance (σ²) d'une loi normale depuis deux valeurs :
    * P(X > 3) = 0.0912 et P(X ≦ -1) = 0.0912
    *
    * Puis calcul de la probabilité de P(X > 0)
    * enfin de x, tel que P(X < x) = 0.036
    */
   @Test
   @DisplayName("Estimation moyenne, variance loi normale depuis P")
   public void estimationMoyenneVarianceLoiNormaleDepuisP() {
      // On va se servir de la valeur centrée réduite qui suit une loi N(0,1)
      // qui permet de substituer à X une valeur Y = (X - µ) / σ
      NormalDistribution N = new NormalDistribution(0, 1);    // μ=0, σ=1
      double t1 = N.inverseCumulativeProbability(0.0912);     // pour P(X ≦ -1) = 0.0912
      double t2 = N.inverseCumulativeProbability(1 - 0.0912); // pour P(X > 3) = 0.0912

      // Les deux équations qui ressortent de ces calculs sont :
      //    3 - µ =  1.334σ (L1)
      //   -1 - µ = -1.334σ (L2)
      // et l'on résout ce système en calculant L1 - L2 qui supprime µ et donne la valeur de σ :
      double sigma = (3.0 - (-1.0)) / (t1 - t2);
      double sigmaCarre = sigma * sigma;
      double mu = 3.0 - t1 * sigma;

      LOGGER.info("Cas 5 : L'espérance mᵧ σ² de X, sachant que P(X ≦ -1) = P(X > 3) = 9.12% valent m={} et σ²={}", mu, sigma);
      assertEquals(1, mu, 0.01, "Mauvaise moyenne pour le cas 5");                  // µ = 1
      assertEquals(1.5 * 1.5, sigmaCarre, 0.01, "Mauvaise variance pour le cas 5"); // σ² = 1.5²

      // Probabilité que P(X > 0) [sachant donc que X ~ N(µ=1, σ²=1.5²)]
      // C'est 1 - F(0)
      N = new NormalDistribution(1, 1.5); // μ=1, σ=1.5
      double pSuperieur0 = 1 - N.cumulativeProbability(0);
      assertEquals(0.7475, pSuperieur0, 0.01, "Mauvaise P(X > 0) pour le cas 5, quand les paramètres de N ont bien été définis");

      // Et x, tel que P(X < x) = 0.036
      double x = N.inverseCumulativeProbability(0.036);
      LOGGER.info("P(X < -2) = {}", N.cumulativeProbability(-2));
      assertEquals(-2, x, 0.01, "Mauvais x tel que P(X < x) = 0.036 pour le cas 5, quand les paramètres de N ont bien été définis");
   }
}
```

Everything is running fine, except for the last question, where it finds
$x = -1.699$ for $P(X < x) = 0.036$,
saying that $P(X < -2) = 0.0228$

and I don't see where I did a mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using R to solve this confirms your figures:

- By symmetry the mean is `mean(c(-1, 3))` i.e. `1`
- The standard deviation is then `((-1) -1) / qnorm(p=0.0912, mean=0, sd=1)` i.e. about `1.5`
- $\mathbb P(X>0)$ is then `1 - pnorm(q=0, mean=1, sd=1.5)` i.e. about `0.7475`
- and the final figure `qnorm(p=0.036, mean=1, sd=1.5)` i.e. about `-1.7`

Comment: So I believe I'm in front of a mistake of my book, which expect me to find -2 instead. And this is sad because it's on it's very first exercise.